# Деплой телеграмм бота Java на TomCat сервер

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Всем привет! подскажите может кто сталкисвался с подобным: есть телеграмм бот написан на Java с использованием LongPolling и tellegamm Api. при запуске из IDE все прекрасно работает. У товарища есть сервер на TomCat после деплоя билда туда бот фактически не работает, хотя сам TomCat показывает что приложение успешно запущено, для тестов также развернул TomCat на локальной машине  и результат аналогичный - приложение запускается по информации сервера но бот на команды не реагирует.

вот ссылка на GitHub на код бота: https://github.com/mixk88/BigBrother_bot

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я не пытался запускать этот проект, но на первый взгляд там 2 проблемы.

1. некорректное чтение файла из ресурсов (дело в том, что читать файл из ресурсов, указав абсолютный путь к нему, некорретно, т.к. при сборке в jar/war этот путь меняется. результат: при запуске из среды разработки все ок, при деплое все падает)
2. куча ненужных зависимостей - это неявная проблема, но добавление любых зависимостей (неиспользуемых), а тем более в совокупности со спринг бут и указанием их версий - поступок храбрый, но глупый. читайте про ад зависимостей и назначение спринг бут.

итого, наведите порядок с зависимостями.
попробуйте переписать свой класс так:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

public class Censor {

    private final static Set<String> dictionary = readFromResource();

    //ловим нежелательные слова_
    public static Boolean check(String inputText) {
        return dictionary.contains(inputText);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private static Set<String> readFromResource() {
        return Files.lines(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:BadWords.txt").toPath())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

p.s. чтобы не заниматься постоянно заворачиванием проверяемых исключений в try-catch с попыткой пробросить что-то непроверяемое, используйте @SneakyThrows, но для этого подключите ломбок (он еще много всего полезного умеет!)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```